# How to print quotes between value using awk

Tags: awk, output, field, separator

I have a file

```
A|B|C|D|E|F
```

I need output like

```
"A","B","C","D","E","F"
```

I did:

```
awk -f'|' '{print $1,$2,$3}'
```

This gives me output just with spaces. My question is how to get comma separated output with quotes, and how to print all values at once without typing `'{print $1,$2,$3......}'`

I can do:

```
awk -f'|' '{print """"$1""""","""""$2""""","""""$3""""..}'
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To specify the field separator, you have to use `-F` instead of `-f`; to change what the field separator is for the output, you have to change the `OFS` variable (the output field separator).

The get quotes around your fields, you can loop over all fields and add them:

```
$ awk -F"|" -v OFS="," '{for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i){$i="\""$i"\""}}1' infile
"A","B","C","D","E","F"
```

Alternatively, using sed:

```
$ sed 's/\([^|]*\)/"\1"/g;y/|/,/' infile
"A","B","C","D","E","F"
```

This surrounds all sequences of non-pipe characters with quotes, then substitutes all the pipes with commas.

Comment: Thak you very much for fast answer. It works great. Lowercase -f was typo from my side :-)

Answer (score 5):

The idiomatic awk solution is to tell awk what the input field separator (FS) is and what you want the output field separator (OFS) to be and then simply update a field so awk converts all FSs to OFSs.

So that could be this:

```
$ awk -F'|' -v OFS='","' '{$1=$1; print "\"" $0 "\""}' file
"A","B","C","D","E","F"
```

or this:

```
$ awk -F'|' -v OFS='","' '{$1=$1; gsub(/^|$/,"\"")} 1' file
"A","B","C","D","E","F"
```

or @karakfa's alternative https://stackoverflow.com/a/35607361/1745001 or various other similar solutions.

Answer (score 4):

another `awk`

```
$ awk -F'|' -v OFS='","' -v q='"' '{$0=q $0 q; $1=$1}1' file

"A","B","C","D","E","F"
```

field separators are handled by `awk` automatically, just needs help for the first and last fields.  Equivalently,

```
$ awk -F'|' -v OFS='","' -v q='"' '{$1=q $1; $NF=$NF q}1' file

"A","B","C","D","E","F"
```

Answer (score -1):

awk -F"|" '{print "\""$1"\",""\""$2"\",""\""$3"\""}'

Comment: You're right, sorry. But it's still hard coded to three fields.